# Deploy breaks when running 'find' on a directory with space in between name

Tags: regex, deployment, find, capistrano

We have encountered a problem recently wherein one of the directory with spaces was used and when we run `find` on the directories recursively. It breaks at the points it finds the directory with space and doesn't move ahead with the deploy. Below is the screenshot of the cap deploy :-

```
*     executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' find /srv/vhosts/static_cap -type d | xargs sudo -p 'sudo password: ' chmod -R 755"
      servers: ["web00.xx.com"]
      [web00.xx.com] executing command
      [web01.xx.com] executing command
**     [out :: web00.xx.com] 
**     [out :: web01.xx.com] 
**     [out :: web00.xx.com] chmod: cannot access `/srv/vhosts/static_cap/public_uploads/xx/0.9/90/Color'
**     [out :: web00.xx.com] : No such file or directory
**     [out :: web00.xx.com] chmod: cannot access `Id': No such file or directory
  command finished in 1133ms
    failed: "sh -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\'' find /srv/vhosts/static_cap -type d | xargs sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\'' chmod -R 755'" on web00.buzzaa.com
```

The directory on which it's trying to run find looks something like this :-

```
xx@web00:~$ ls -ld /srv/vhosts/xx_cap/xx/0.9/90/Color\ Id/
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 root webadmins 4096 Jun 11 07:26 /srv/vhosts/xx_cap/xx/0.9/90/Color Id/
```

Is there a way can take this directory name as one rather than breaking at regex character ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like find command treats every directory with a delimiter of space as an individual directory that's why it takes "Color" and "Id" as two different directories. Well it's a known problem in Capistrano 2.x as well and occurs for find command https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/300. 
     My case was to just change the ownership of all the files inside a directory, so the way I handled is to simple call the chown command rather than a find with a pipe :-

task :nimbuzz_bef_prem do
    transaction do
        run "#{sudo} chmod -R 755 #{deploy_to}"
        run "#{sudo} chown -R www-data:xyz #{deploy_to}"
    end
  end